# NASM linking libraries during runtime

Tags: assembly, nasm, shellcode

This post on windows shellcoding that i came across shows how to make a simple shellcode for Sleep function that is located in kernel32.dll. I understand the code but it seems as though that you can't call the function without knowing the exact address of the function in the library for which you have to use `arwin32.exe` that's provided by the author of the post.

```
;sleep.asm
[SECTION .text]

global _start


_start:
        xor eax,eax
        mov ebx, 0x77e61bea ;address of Sleep
        mov ax, 5000        ;pause for 5000ms
        push eax
        call ebx        ;Sleep(ms);
```

[Shellcoding for Linux and Windows](http://www.vividmachines.com/shellcode/shellcode.html#win32ex1)

In MASM32, one simply includes the libraries and dll's but I don't know if this is the same case in NASM, i tried to include kernel32.lib using RadAasm but got error.

Undefined Reference to Sleep.

My question is: How would one call the Sleep function in NASM without knowing the exact address of any of the functions, neither GetProcAddress or the like.

NOTE: Even the other examples, he provides absolute addresses for the functions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nasm on windows, but have you tried `nasm -f bin source.asm`? (or win32 for windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [extern](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5) keyword.

For example:

```
section .text

extern Sleep

global Start
Start:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  push 2000
  call Sleep
  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
  ret
```

You have to link the compiled object file with the kernel32.dll. Here is how it is done with GoLink:

```
nasm -f win32 sleep.asm -o sleep.obj
GoLink /files /console sleep.obj kernel32.dll
```

You can find GoLink here: [www.godevtool.com/Golink.zip](http://www.godevtool.com/Golink.zip)

You probably have to use GetProcAddress with hardcoded address if you need functions from other libraries without using extern at all. kernel32.dll is loaded automatically to same address for every process so Sleep (and other kernel32 functions) should have constant address. So you have to use some tool to get the address of the desired function and then use that as hardcoded value (like in the example). I actually tried this long time ago and it worked but I suspect that it depends on the Windows version.

Comment: unfortunately, i'm a beginner to asm so if it isn't too much to ask, please comment your code. :) i understand the part where you're calling sleep with the push 2000 param but the other 2 above that are sorta new.

Comment: and I don't have GoLink, should I download it?

Comment: Added link to GoLink to answer. The lines above `push` and below `call` are just basic stack frame stuff that is not really required in this case (you can read more about stack frames and calling conventions here: [http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html))

Comment: i appreciate your answer, it works but it doesn't answer my question entirely. it is supposed to generate shellcode but the obj file created has null bytes unlike the one in the example that's hardcoded.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. So you want some hardcoded address to show up in the generated code without using hardcoded address?

Comment: yeah, something of the sort or is that not possible?

Comment: @Hawk Edited answer a bit. I think that the exact thing you are trying to accomplish is not possible but the way you see in the linked example is pretty much how this kind of thing can be done.